# Convert a text file of column and row names to a sparse matrix

Tags: r, performance, algorithm, indexing, sparse-matrix

I would like to take column and row names from a text file and build a sparse matrix using the row and column information (the algorithm can be found in the description below). I have a working solution but it is slow for a text file with over 3,000,000 entries.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a faster algorithm than the one I describe below?

First, I start with a text file which provides column and row names, separated by a space. For example:

```
aaaa 11111 22222 33333 bbbb 11111 22222 cccc 11111
```

where `{aaaa,bbbb,cccc}` are 4 character column names and `{11111,22222,33333}` are 5 character row names.

Second, I load this text file into `R` using the scan function:

```
char_vec <- scan(file = "textFile.txt", what = "character")
```

which converts the textFile information into a character vector.

Third, I find all of the possible column names and row names:

```
c_names <- unique(char_vec[nchar(char_vec) == 4])
r_names <- unique(char_vec[nchar(char_vec) == 5])
```

Fourth, I create a sparse matrix from the data:

```
library(Matrix)
createMatrix <- function(char_vec=char_vec, c_names=c_names, r_names=r_names)
{
  mySparseMatrix <- Matrix(0, nrow = length(r_names), ncol = length(c_names), 
  sparse = TRUE)
  for (i1 in 1:length(char_vec))
  {
    if (char_vec[i1] %in% c_names)
    {
      c_index <- match(char_vec[i1], c_names)
    }
    if (char_vec[i1] %in% r_names)
    {
      r_index <- match(char_vec[i1], r_names)
      mySparseMatrix[r_index, c_index] <- 1
    }
  }
  colnames(mySparseMatrix) <- c_names
  rownames(mySparseMatrix) <- r_names
  return(mySparseMatrix)
}
```

This gives this output:

```
      aaaa bbbb cccc
11111    1    1    1
22222    1    1    .
33333    1    .    .
```

To show how fast this algorithm works, I padded out the character vector (albeit in an unrealistic manner but I think it serves its purpose as an example):

```
char_vec <- rep(c("aaaa", "11111", "22222", "33333", "bbbb", "11111", "22222", "cccc", "11111"), 1000)
```

and then ran:

```
system.time(createMatrix(char_vec, c_names, r_names))
```

Output:

```
   user  system elapsed 
   9.89    0.00    9.94
```

I have profiled the function using:

```
Rprof("createMatrixOut.out")
z <- createMatrix(char_vec, c_names, r_names)
Rprof(NULL)
```

and display a subset of the output using:

```
summaryRprof("createMatrixOut.out")$by.total[1:10,]
```

Output:

```
                  total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"createMatrix"          8.08    100.00      0.08     0.99
"[<-"                   7.96     98.51      0.08     0.99
"replCmat4"             7.40     91.58      0.04     0.50
"as"                    5.64     69.80      0.04     0.50
"asMethod"              5.06     62.62      0.16     1.98
"standardGeneric"       4.68     57.92      0.24     2.97
"new"                   4.52     55.94      0.02     0.25
"initialize"            4.40     54.46      0.04     0.50
"callNextMethod"        4.24     52.48      0.08     0.99
".Call"                 4.12     50.99      0.60     7.43
```

Comment: Did you try to profile your code to see where it is taking so much time ?

Comment: I have not no. I shall profile the code and edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the structure of the data: Instead of storing them in a character vector, I create list:

```
> lst
$aaaa
[1] "11111" "22222" "33333"

$bbbb
[1] "11111" "22222"

$cccc
[1] "11111"
```

It is than much faster to iterate through this list

```
createMatrix2 <- function(char_vec=char_vec, c_names=c_names, r_names=r_names)
{
  # create list
  lst <- list()
  for (i1 in 1:length(char_vec))
  {
    if (nchar(char_vec[i1])==4)
    {
      cn <- char_vec[i1]
    } else {
      if (!(char_vec[i1] %in% lst[[cn]])){lst[[cn]] <- c(lst[[cn]],char_vec[i1])}
    }

  }

  # create empty matrix
  mySparseMatrix <- Matrix(0, nrow = length(r_names), ncol = length(c_names), 
                           sparse = TRUE)

  # fill the matrix
  for (cn in names(lst)){
    c_index <- match(cn, c_names)
    for(rn in lst[[cn]]){
      r_index <- match(rn, r_names)
      mySparseMatrix[r_index, c_index] <- 1
    }
  }

  # names and return
  colnames(mySparseMatrix) <- c_names
  rownames(mySparseMatrix) <- r_names
  return(mySparseMatrix)
}


> system.time(createMatrix(char_vec, c_names, r_names))
   user  system elapsed 
   9.60    0.00   10.36 

> system.time(createMatrix2(char_vec, c_names, r_names))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.06    0.00    0.06
```

Comment: I works for me with the sample data you gave. You may use data in slightly different format, which could cause error while creating the list. Could you post the data that you actually use? Do they start with a column name? (four characters long string)

Comment: Sorry, for the previous comment which I have now deleted. I am now running your suggested algorithm on a file with >3,000,000 column and row names. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you Zbynek, this was faster.